# How can I install numpy on prefix?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, numpy

How can I make sure my python uses numpy from my prefix? When I `pip3-` or `conda- install` it, I get a

> ModuleNotFound Error

error.

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\LorenzKort\Miniconda3\envs\panda2env
  package name: numpy
```

Comment: run `conda update conda` and reply if it worked

Comment: Also didn't work to find the numpy module when running my file

Answer (score 0):

According to logs you're in a anaconda virtual environment called "panda2env". Try the following steps:

- Open the Anaconda Prompt
- Activate the virtual environment by typing: activate panda2env
- Verify if numpy is in your list of packages by typing: conda list
- If numpy is not installed (which is highly possible) type: conda install numpy

Comment: It didn't solve the issue! numpy appears in conda list, but does not work when imported in a python file.

Comment: Does your file point to the correct python exe? That is the exe in the virtual environment.